# not getting any response from server, but able to get response from telnet

Tags: java, networking, telnet

I am fist connecting through vpn client then I am able to do telnet and also able to get response when i paste request string on terminal.

Same request if I am trying through java program, I am not getting any response.

I can see using netstat there is established TCP connection when i try through java.
 TCP    10.2.2.22:1154         184.23.23.61:7565       ESTABLISHED

Here is the java client code which sends the request.

```
        Socket client = new Socket(serverIp, port);
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        String test = "TUE231363**";

        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer("response : ");
        out.write(test.getBytes());
        out.flush();

        int c;
        System.out.println("waiting for response.......>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            if (isEndOfResponse(c))
                break;
            System.out.print((char) c);
            response.append(c);
        }
        client.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

every time after few minutes [5-6 min] it exits without any response.

I am bit new to networking, can anyone suggest what I am missing.

Comment: Why don't you try to debug you server code first, after sending the request from client?

Comment: Are you sure your request is not being blocked by some sort of firewall?  The behavior you are seeing seems similar to a situation like that.  Are you able to see the request make to the server?

Comment: I am sure there is no firewall issue on client side. and since I am able to get proper response from server through telnet, there should not be on server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are telnetting to the same IP address and port that you are trying to connect to from Java.

The fact that `telnet` connects, and your client also appears to connect would imply that the server is running, and that it has created an bound a `ServerSocket` on the right IP / host.  It is probably even calling `accept` properly.  But is seems like the server is either not reading the request at all, or it is failing to send a response.

Either way, the problem is most likely on the server side ... and there's not much we can say without seeing the server-side code.

Comment: I don't have control over server code, I have received only Server address and port. and consulting team from server are saying that there isn't any issue from there side since I am able to get proper response from server through telnet.

Comment: If you can get a proper response through telnet, there must be something wrong with you are sending the request in the Java client.  However, since you've not described the protocol to us, we can only guess.  (My guess is that you've left off a CR/LF or something.)

Comment: thanks Stephen,
found that in my request String Ctrl+s was missing,
I have added "\u0013" in the request String and I am getting proper response.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  It was not clear to me from your Question that you were trying to implement "telnet".  But the lesson (I guess) is that it pays to read the protocol spec. document when trying to implement a standard protocol from the ground up.